# $B\subset S$ is closed in $S$ iff it is equal to the intersection of $S$ with some closed subset of $X$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $S$ is a subspace of $X$. Prove that a subset $B\subset S$ is closed in $S$
if and only if it is equal to the intersection of $S$ with some closed subset of $X$.

I tried a lot of things, don't know what else to try.

We have $S-B=S\cap V$ for some $V$ open in $X$
and want to show it's equivalent to
$B=S\cap W$ for some $W$ closed in $X$
Thats how far I get.

This is exercise 3.2 of Lee topological manifolds.

Comment: How do you define 'closed in $S$'?

Comment: This is the definition! You cannot prove the definition.

Comment: Closed means its comlplement is open which means that its the intersection of S with an open set of X

Comment: Can you prove this question for open subset ?

Comment: subset $B\subset S$ is open in S if and only if it is equal to the intersection of S with some open subset of X

Comment: Mojt , We assume what you said

Comment: @user41404: see here:http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjACahUKEwi08qqd3oXGAhVLXSwKHZYpAAs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.u.arizona.edu%2F~mwalker%2Fecon519%2FEcon519LectureNotes%2FOpen%26ClosedSets.pdf&ei=P394VfTWLsu6sQGW04BY&usg=AFQjCNHyHiemI7bhs0Sl6MuFuNqt2sX6UQ&sig2=qkaMSdMlNfMcvHSalaFq5g&bvm=bv.95039771,bs.1,d.bGg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $B\subseteq S$ is closed in $S$.  Then $S\setminus B$ is open in $S$ by definition of closed set, and by definition of the subspace topology $S\setminus B=S\cap U$ for some open set $U\subseteq X$.  Now we have the following:

$$B=S\setminus(S\setminus B)=S\setminus(S\cap U)=S\setminus U=S\cap(X\setminus U)$$

Moreover $X\setminus U$ is closed in $X$ by definition of a closed set.  Hence $B$ is an intersection of $S$ and some closed subset of $X$ as desired, and the forward implication follows.

Suppose $B=S\cap K$ for some closed $K\subseteq X$.  Thus we have that

$$S\setminus B=S\setminus(S\cap K)=S\setminus K=S\cap(X\setminus K)$$

and $X\setminus K$ is open by definition of closed set, so by definition of the subspace topology $S\setminus B$ is open in $S$.  Hence $B$ is closed in $S$ by definition, and the reverse implication follows.

Comment: What is meant by definition of the subspace topology?

Comment: @SimónRamírezAmaya The open subsets of a subspace $S \subseteq X$ are the sets of the form $S \cap U$ for where $U$ is an open subset of $X$.